# Getting 'PXE-561: Media test failure, check cable' errors when I attempt to boot. What's wrong?

Tags: boot

One user asked me to try advance method and I'm not able to boot into any OS now.
I'm just getting

```
PXE-561: Media test failure, check cable
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel Boot Agent
```

and it's restarting itself.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/575015/need-to-dualboot-ubuntu-and-windows-8-1

Here's the image of my hdd info:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are getting "PXE-561: Media test failure, check cable PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel Boot Agent " because you have the system set to boot from the network in the BIOS. Revert the BIOS to defaults, save changes and exit and this will likely solve your problem immediately. If not comment on what happened instead

Comment: Or just change the boot order. I don't think recommending a total BIOS revert is the best option here. +1 nevertheless.

Comment: @Seth I considered it the best option as the OP didn't know what was wrong from the output. Either approach is likely to work if done correctly.